# R Regex capture group?

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a lot of strings like this:

```
2019/01/01/07/556662_cba3a4fc-cb8f-4150-859f-5f21a38373d0
```

I want to extract the substring that lays right after the last `"/"` and ends with `"_"`:

```
556662
```

I have found out how to extract: `/01/01/07/556662`

by using the following regex: `(\/)(.*?)(?=\_)`

Please advise how can I capture the right group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
x <- "2019/01/01/07/556662_cba3a4fc-cb8f-4150-859f-5f21a38373d0"
regmatches(x, regexpr(".*/\\K[^_]+", x, perl=TRUE))
## [1] "556662"
```

See the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/CjiKyz/1) and [R demo](https://ideone.com/sQfTLG).

Here, the regex matches and outputs the first substring that matches

- `.*/` - any 0+ chars as many as possible up to the last `/`
- `\K` - omits this part from the match
- `[^_]+` - puts 1 or more chars other than `_` into the match value.

Or, a `sub` solution:

```
sub(".*/([^_]+).*", "\\1", x)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CjiKyz/2).

Here, it is similar to the previous one, but the 1 or more chars other than `_` are *captured* into Group 1 (`\1` in the replacement pattern) and the trailing `.*` make sure the whole input is matched (and consumed, ready to be replaced).

**Alternative non-base R solutions**

If you can afford or prefer to work with `stringi`, you may use

```
library(stringi)
stri_match_last_regex("2019/01/01/07/556662_cba3a4fc-cb8f-4150-859f-5f21a38373d0", ".*/([^_]+)")[,2]
## [1] "556662"
```

This will match a string up to the last `/` and will capture into Group 1 (that you access in Column 2 using `[,2]`) 1 or more chars other than `_`.

Or

```
stri_extract_last_regex("2019/01/01/07/556662_cba3a4fc-cb8f-4150-859f-5f21a38373d0", "(?<=/)[^_/]+")
## => [1] "556662"
```

This will extract the last match of a string that consists of 1 or more chars other than `_` and `/` after a `/`.

Comment: Brilliant easy and straight to the point professional solution! Thanks Wiktor!!! @wiktor-stribizew

Comment: @SteveS I added non base R regex solutions, too.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a capturing group:

```
/([^_/]+)_[^/\s]*
```

**Explanation**

- `/` Match literally
- `([^_/]+)` Capture in a group matching not an underscore or forward slash
- `_[^/\s]*` Match `_` and then 0+ times not a forward slash or a whitespace character

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XFnRtD/1) | [R demo](https://ideone.com/AM8jXX)

One option to get the capturing group might be to get the second column using str_match:

```
library(stringr)
str = c("2019/01/01/07/556662_cba3a4fc-cb8f-4150-859f-5f21a38373d0")
str_match(str, "/([^_/]+)_[^/\\s]*")[,2]

# [1] "556662"
```

Comment: This is not what I need, I want to extract anything that lays between last / and before  _

Comment: @SteveS That is in the first capturing group. I have updated my answer.

Comment: but I don't need anything after the substring that lays between last / and before _.

Comment: How can I extract the only part I need.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the Regex rules according to the code of Wiktor Stribiżew.

```
x <- "2019/01/01/07/556662_cba3a4fc-cb8f-4150-859f-5f21a38373d0"
regmatches(x, regexpr(".*/([0-9]+)", x, perl=TRUE))
sub(".*/([0-9]+).*", "\\1", x)
```

### Output

[1] "2019/01/01/07/556662"

[1] "556662"

### R [demo](https://ideone.com/xsOFjV)

Comment: Note that OP does not mention in the post that after the last `/` and before the next `_` there should be digits only.